# Python function skipped during execution

Tags: python, function, skip, cryptocurrency

I'm trying to create a simple script to buy and sell a specified cryptocurrency on the Binance exchange. Below is a snippet of the buy and sell functions which create the buy and sell orders.

```
from binance.client import Client 

'api_key' = 'xxxxxxxxxxxx' 
'secret' = 'xxxxxxxxxxxx'  

client = Client(api_key, api_secret)  
def create_buy():     
    try:         
        buy_order = client.order_limit_buy(symbol='ETHUSDT', quantity=1, price='1500')         
        print(str(buy_order ))         
        create_sell()     
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        pass
def create_sell():     
    try:         
        sleep(1)         
        sell_order= client.order_limit_sell(symbol='ETHUSDT', quantity=1, price='2000')
        print(str(sell_order))  
        exit()   
    except Exception as e:         
        print(e.message)         
        pass 

if __name__ == '__main__':    
    create_buy()
```

Most of the times, it'll have no trouble running from start to finish and return `Bought` and `Sold` with no issues and then exit the program.
However, there are times in which it would just skip `create_sell()`. I know this because I always get a return with `create_buy()` but then the program exits immediately without calling `create_sell()`. I thought that this could be due to latency issue between the exchange and me but wouldn't I be able to catch that?

Would it make a difference if I put `create_sell()` outside the try block or in the main block so it reads?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are calling create_buy() from some other place in your code as it is working as expected in most of the times, With that I think there are two cases where it might be failing.

1. In create_buy(), client.order_limit_buy might be throwing an exception. You need to print this to your log file or some other place to check.
   Also if you are sure, create_sell() should be called even when in case of exception, write a finally block and move call to create_sell() into finally block
2. The other possibility is call to client.order_limit_sell in create_sell() might be throwing an exception, Do check it.

Comment: 1. If client.order_limit_buy was to throw an exception, it would be caught in the except block and I have used this to debug many times. However, I will implement the finally and see if it makes any changes. It's just strange that when I debug the program, it exits after create_buy() without throwing any exception so that makes me wonder would the program reach the finally block?
2. If an exception is thrown, it should've been caught with the except block, right? I'll add some print statements at the beginning of create_sell() to see if the program actually calls it.

Comment: As per my understanding, finally block is called always. Try to print all possible values like symbol etc in the exception block to see when it mg=ight be throwing exception.
BTW are you sure, whether "client.order_limit_buy" is a synchronous function and it returns only when the transaction is completed? If it is asynchronous and returning before the transaction is completed, sell may throw exception.

Comment: client.order_limit_buy is a synchronous function to my understanding.